# How to reload a HTML table without refreshing the whole page while working with Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am using Spring MVC , example.jsp file  with Javascript.
I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Is it possible to use Javascript to laod new data from DB into HTML tables without refreshing the whole page?

I just don't want my whole page being replaced when new data is loaded into table with some event.

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried?

Comment: Not much After working for 3 years in Desktop with java and spring , i am a month old in Web, so i didn't tried much sP00m , looked on some 30-40 links on web .. nothing informing me with spring MVC .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reload a part of you page using JavaScript, basically AJAX.
This is how you should do it.

### Client Side

Let's assume that you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as a JavaScript Framework.
You'll need to use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the Client Side.

```js
var successHandler = function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  // After success reload table with JavaScript
  // based on data...
};

var errorHandler = function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  // Error handler. AJAX request failed.
  // 404 or KO from server...
  alert('Something bad happened while reloading the table.');
};

var reloadData = function() { 
  // Process your request
  var request = new Object();
  request.id = 'some id'; // some data

  // Make the AJAX call
  jQuery.ajax({
    type       : 'POST',
    url        : 'http://domain/context/reload-data-url',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data       : JSON.stringify(request)
    success    : successHandler,
    error      : errorHandler
  });
};
```

Call the `reloadData()` function when you need to reload the table.

### Server Side

You're using Spring MVC. Then your Controller should look like:

```java
 // Spring MVC Controller
 @Controller
 public class ReloadDataController {

   // Request Mapping
   @RequestMapping(value = '/reload-data-url', method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<String> processReloadData(@RequestBody String body) {

     // Get your request
     JSONObject request = new JSONObject(body);
     String id = request.getString("id"); // Here the value is 'some id'

     // Get the new data in a JSONObject
     JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
     // build the response...

     // Send the response back to your client
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(response.toString(),
                headers, HttpStatus.OK);
   }

 }
```

You don't have to use JSON but I think this is the best way.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stucked into it than i finally found this solution which use `ModelAndView`
See this solution it may work
[Thymeleaf table update without page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723711/thymeleaf-table-update-without-page-reload)

My answer would be late but someone might help...

Comment: Please include an example or some kind of code instead of linking to solely outside resources, as those resources may change or vanish.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).