# Refresh part of parent when child window closes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, window

Page 1: tabeloverzicht.php

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tabel overzicht</title>
<link href="../css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../css/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $.get(
        'tabel.php', 
        function(response){
            $('#tabelplaats').html(response);
        }
    );
    });

    $(window).click(function(event){
        $.get(
        'tabel1.php',
        function(response){
            $('#tabelplaats').html(response);
        }
    );
}); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tabelplaats">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Page 2: tabel.php

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="../css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Tabel Processor</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "',  'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=600,h eight=500,left = 200,top = 200');");
}
// End -->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Hallo</th>
    <th>dit</th>
    <th>is</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>een</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><a HREF="javascript:popUp('popup.php')"><div id="modify" class="buttonsmall"><button id="BedrijfAanpassen" class="button" name="modify"><i class="icon-pencil icon-small"></i></button></div></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Page 3: Tabel1.php

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="../css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Tabel Processor</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=600,height=500,left = 200,top = 200');");
}
// End -->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Page4: popup.php

---

Doesn't matter whats on this page.

Tabeloverzicht is the main page. Here is a table displayed. This table containes a button which opens a popup window (in my application you can change some values of the table in the popup window) When the popup is closed he needs to update the table in the parent window. window.opener.reload(true) doesn't work for me as there are many other options on the main page which will be reset then aswell. I only need to update the top table.

Further in my application there will be a second table and depending on which popup window is opened he needs te refresh either the first or the second table.

Hope anyone can help, as I'm stuck with this problem for days now...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the values in the table come from a database you would need to do an AJAX call to update that specific table. Check out this link for more details: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458540/how-to-reload-a-html-table-without-refreshing-the-whole-page-while-working-with).

Comment: can you please summarize all in something small instead dumping all the things. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you will need to have an callback function in the main page and inside that you can do whatever ...

for example :
index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            <!-- Begin
            function popUp(URL) {
                day = new Date();
                id = day.getTime();
                eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=600,height=500,left = 200,top = 200');");
            }
        // End -->
            function callback_top(){
                console.log("callback_top()");
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="popUp('pop.html');">Press me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

pop.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // solution 1
        function calltop(){
            window.opener.callback_top();
        }
        // solution 2
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            window.opener.callback_top();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="calltop();">Press me 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```