# Thymeleaf table update without page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am rendering datawith thymeleaf attribute. But i am implementing "Search" button now, and want to do it without reload.

I have attribute `depatments` which render `List<Department>` from db
I know, how to do it via **ajax**, but then i need to replace attribute with RestController, who will give me JSON.
Is it posible to fetch data from attribute without reloading page? Ajax, or js, or something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using fragment and ajax. In your controller

```
@GetMapping("/url")
public ModelAndView getResultBySearchKey()
    {
        List<depatments> areaList= new ArrayList<>();//results from db
        ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("search::search_list"); 
        mv.addObject("searchList",areaList);

        return mv;
    }
```

and in your search.html add bellow code. And don't forget to use inline javascript.

```js
function loadSearchResult()
      {
       
       $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: /*[[ @{'/url'} ]]*/,
       
         success: function(data){
        
          /*<![CDATA[*/
          
          
          $('.search_list').html(data);
          
          
          /*]]>*/
        },
         
       })
       
      }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
th:onclick="'loadSearchResult();'">Search</button>
    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-md-12 search_list">
       <div class="table-responsive" th:fragment="search_list">
         <table
         class="table  table-bordered ">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>SL No.</th>
               <th>Actions</th>
               <th>Name</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
        <tbody>
    <!-- your desired rows-->
        </tbody>
```